# Undefined class property

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
///DATA MODEL
class Data extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function read_record(){
        $q = $this->db->get('category');
        return $q->result();
    }
}

//in Controller
class Test_admin extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('data');
        $dat = array();
        if( $q = $this->data->read_record()){
         $dat['record'] = $q;
        }
        $this->load->view('test', $dat);
    }
}

// in view
<?php
foreach ($record as $row){
    echo $row->name;
    echo '<br />';
}  
?>
```

Error shown:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$name
>
> Filename: views/test.php
>
> Line Number: 35
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\ci312\application\views\test.php
>      Line: 35
>      Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\ci312\application\controllers\test_admin.php
>      Line: 9
>      Function: view
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\ci312\index.php
>      Line: 315
>      Function: require_once

Comment: you cannot pass the `$q` to `$dat['record]` because, `$q` is an object not an array, it should be `$dat['record] = (array) $q` then `print_r($record)` for the record to view.

Answer (score -1):

Add in a var_dump() in your view code to examine what you are passing in...

**in view**

```
 <?php

 var_dump($record); // Debug
 exit(); // Debug
 foreach ($record as $row){
    echo $row->name;
    echo '<br />';
 }
```

Comment: To the Down voter.... So now showing someone how to debug and look at what is going on is frowned upon. Who knew!